# How to start a gitlab pipeline job that fails when test coverage goes below a threshold

Tags: jestjs, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

We have jest unit testing for our react app and need to set a threshold value of 80% test case coverage. I know that we can get the coverage report in `npm test -- --coverage --watchAll=false` but I am now tasked with failing the pipeline if the coverage goes below 80%.  I saw that there is a test pipeline stage which is commented right now.
I have the following script, I need to somehow get the coverage, and compare if it is 80 or more else fail the pipleline, what should I do

```
test:
  stage: test
  image: node:16.13.1
  before_script:
    - npm i
    - npx node -v
    - npx npm -v
  script:
    - echo "running test coverage"
    - npm test -- --coverage --watchAll=false
  coverage: '/All files[^|]*\|[^|]*\s+([\d\.]+)/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your script section you should be able to use a Regex expression to retrieve the coverage value from the report.

Then you can use some bash scripting to remove the % sign from the output and compare the value with your required minimum. If the value is below, simply return false which I think gitlab should interpret as a failure.

If it’s above your minimum value return true and it should pass the job.

Comment: I saw gitlab uses something called coverage for getting the regex form but it does not allow how to extract just that value from the npm test -- --coverage --watchAll=false .  Not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: You can use something like sed as a separate command within your script: section to grab the same value and use it how I described above. 
The gitlab coverage keyword will consume the value and use it within some of your pipeline metrics.

Comment: Not sure if you made it work but this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70836517/how-can-i-set-a-minimum-unit-test-coverage-with-gitlab-ci